# Rearrange column with empty values using awk or sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed, multiple-columns

i want to rearrange the columns of a txt file, but there are empty values, which cause a problem. For example:

testfile:

```
Name    ID      Count   Date    Other
A       1       10      513     x
        6       15      312     x
        3       18      314     x
B       19      31      942     x
        8       29      722     x
```

when i tried `$ more testfile |awk '{print $2"\t"$1"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5}'`
it becomes:

```
ID      Name    Count   Date    Other
1       A       10      513     x
15      6       312     x
18      3       314     x
19      B       31      942     x
29      8       722     x
```

which is not i want, please help,i want it to be

```
ID      Name    Count   Date    Other
1       A       10      513     x
15              6       312     x
18              3       314     x
19      B       31      942     x
29              8       722     x
```

moreover i am not sure which columns might contain empty values, and the column length is not fixed, thank you

Comment: Is the input file by any chance already tab-separated? Try `awk -F'\t' ...` and see what it does. Also post the output you DO want, not just the output you don't want. If the input file is not tab-separated then the best solution will be GNU awk with `FIELDWIDTHS` - do you have GNU awk (`awk --version` will tell you)?

Comment: @EdMorton, yes, my file is tab-separated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input file is not tab-separated and you have (or can get) GNU awk then I recommend:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="8 8 8 8 8" -v OFS='\t' '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
    }
    t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t'
}1' file
ID      Name    Count   Date    Other
1       A       10      513     x
6               15      312     x
3               18      314     x
19      B       31      942     x
8               29      722     x
```

If your file is tab-separated then all you need is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t}1' file
```

Comment: my file is tab-separated and your above comment is the answer!Thanks!! The following command works
`$ more file|awk -F'\t' '{print $2"\t"$1"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5}' > newfile`

Comment: May be you can edit this answer, and i can check it as correct answer, thanks!

Comment: OK, I added the right solution for a tab-separated input file.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural model for `awk` to use is columns as defined by the transitions from white-space to non-white-space and back. Since you have columns that may themselves be white-space, the natural model won't work.

However, you can revert to using a model based on column *positions* rather than transitions, meaning that a file containing only spaces (the presence of tabs will complicate things):

```
Name    ID      Count   Date    Other
A       1       10      513     x
        6       15      312     x
        3       18      314     x
B       19      31      942     x
        8       29      722     x
```

can still be rearranged, though not as succinctly as transition-based columns.

The following `awk` script will do the trick, swapping `name` and `id`:

```
{
    name  = substr($0, 1,7);
    id    = substr($0, 9,7);
    count = substr($0,17,7);
    date  = substr($0,25,7);
    other = substr($0,33  );
    print id" "name" "count" "date" "other;
}
```

If the original file is called `pax.in` and the `awk` script is stored in `pax.awk`, the command `awk -f pax.awk pax.in` will give you, as desired:

```
ID      Name    Count   Date    Other
1       A       10      513     x
6               15      312     x
3               18      314     x
19      B       31      942     x
8               29      722     x
```

Keep in mind I've written that script to be relatively flexible, allowing you to change the order of the columns quite easily. If all you want is to swap the first two columns, you could use:

```
awk '{print substr($0,9,8)substr($0,1,8)substr($0,17)}' qq.in
```

or the slightly shorter (if you're allowed to use other tools):

```
sed -E 's/^(.{8})(.{8})/\2\1/' qq.in
```

Comment: The `""`s between the `substr()s` in your final awk command are doing nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk alternative is using the number of fields.  If you know your data and it's only deficit in the first column you can try this.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'NF==4{$5=$4;$4=$3;$3=$2;$2=$1;$1=""} {print $2,$1,$3,$4,$5}'
```

However, the output will be tab separated instead of fixed length format.  You can achieve the same using printf and changing OFS, but perhaps tab separated is what you really need for tabular representation.

Comment: this works for the small test file, but not work well for my data, not sure why

Comment: test your data with `awk '{print NF}'` to check how many fields awk sees.  Based on your sample data it should be 4 or 5.